# winter bash のメッセージについて

Tags: バグ, サポート

年輪バッジをもらい、帽子ももらったのですが、
メッセージには
925 を手にいれた！
と出ています。
925 とは年輪バッジのことだと思うのですが、
何か変換ミスが起こっているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winter Bash で貰える帽子の中に[「925」](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/925) という物があり、それの取得条件が、

> earn a silver badge / 銀バッジを獲得する

なので、銀バッジである[年輪バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=3054)を獲得すると同時にこの「925」という帽子も手に入ったという事だと思います。

Comment: 925 って特定の帽子のことだったのですね。てっきり帽子は文や単語で表されているものだと思っていました。